# How Chrome installs app on Android directly

Tags: android

I am just curious to know how the Chrome browser installs app on the Phone.
What is the mechanism behind it?

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: Do you mean http://market.android.com? This is a web site. Chrome has nothing to do with it. It works also from other browsers.

Comment: Yes... I want to know how does it work? What is the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push notification service, the market has its "own" push notifications implemented. When we installed a couple apps from the page, they installed almost immediately. This isn't the phone asking if there are installs pending, this is the market site pushing the info directly to the device.

If you disable sync, it will stop push notifications too.

Your phone market Google account also linked to the android market,  thats the reason that you need to sign in before you install apps from webstore

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)

Comment: Does it mean they use SMSes for sending install intent to the phone?

Comment: No.. they don't sent SMS but Push Technology, and you need internet connection for this to works , the Android Market server will sent the information to the device  market,  more information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: Try Google ' Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)'